# URL doesn't change after redirecting

Tags: angular

As the title said that I failed to redirect to the component of the default direct.
When I try to visit localhost:4200, it never navigate to localhost:4200/workbench
appRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/workbench', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'**', component:PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

homeRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent,
    children:[
      {path:'workbench',component:WorkbenchComponent},
    ]
  }
];
```

app.Moudule:

```
  imports: [
    ...
    HomeModule,
    AccountModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
```

Do anyone have this experience and know how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper routing would be the following:

**AppModule:**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

**AppRoutingModule:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: homeRoutingRoutes },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export
```

**HomeRoutingModule**

```js
export const homeRoutingRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'workbench', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path:'workbench', component: WorkbenchComponent }
]
```

So what is not working between the original code and this?

There is no `path: 'workbench'` registered in the **AppRoutingModule**. If there is no path registered, Angular will always push the navigation to the `path: '**'` route.

If you want to redirect directly to the `path: 'workbench` then you need to declare it in the **AppRoutingModule**, not in a child under it, like so:

**AppRoutingModule:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'workspace', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'workbench', component: WorkbenchComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent
];
```

Note that doing so means the **HomeComponent** no longer is necessary.

Comment: I didn't try it but I think your reply makes sence, the redirect target path should be registered in the same module which redirect from.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to child route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent,
    children:[
      {path:'workbench',component:WorkbenchComponent},
     {path:'', redirectTo:'/workbench', pathMatch:'full'},
     {path:'**', component:PageNotFoundComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't understand. Do you mean put these lines to AppRoutingModule? Home component is already  decleared in homemodule

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not what I prefer, I solved this problem to add a path to home feature module like below:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'home',
    component:HomeComponent,
    canActivate:[authGuard],
    children:[
      {path:'workbench',component:WorkbenchComponent},

    ]
  }
];
```

and make the redirect to

```js
{path:'', redirectTo:'/home/workbench', pathMatch:'full'},
```

It works finally to `localhost:4200/home/workbench`. If anyone has any better way to make the redirecting route shorter to localhost:4200/workbench please share.